# how to make link text “close” instead of cross icon appear in jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In a run-of-the-mill jQuery dialog, you see a cross icon in the top right-hand corner. When you click it, the dialog window closes. The underlying HTML looks as follows:

```
    <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button">
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
    </a>
```

In lieu of the cross icon, I want the “close” text link to be visible. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that and modify it however else you'd like with CSS:

```
.ui-icon-closethick {
    background-image: none;
    text-indent: 0;
    width: 50px;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    right: 1.3em
}
```

Comment: It works. I tested using chrome dev inspector on http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/. You can use CSS to change basically *any* part of the look and feel. Just make sure your styles appear after the jQuery UI css, or makes sure to use `!important`.

Comment: To Emmett -- Dude, I appreciate your effort, but it’s no good. I have an MVC 4 internet template based project. I’ve stuck your two rules in the site.css file. When I call up the dialog, I see a semblance of “close” in the upper right-hand corner, but there are two problems. Uno, when I mouse the text I see a square around the text. Due, there’s no way of styling the text. No offence, but I didn’t need you to discover this. I had seen this phenomenon well before I asked my question at this forum, and I had tried more “devious” tricks then your two rules.

Comment: a) "I see a square around the text" ..ok so use CSS to widen the square. b) "there’s no way of styling the text" ..yes there is, it's called CSS. Again, you absolutely can modify the look of the dialog however you please using just CSS.